# Sorting an array of strings having alphanumeric values (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have an array having values as following : ['1.hello', '10.hel', '12B.hepl', '9.hell', '12A.help', '2.helo']

I want these sorted as : ['1.hello', '2.helo', '9.hell', '10.hel', '12A.help', '12B.hepl']

Any regex solution would also be preferred. Anything after the `.` is not to be considered for sorting the array

Comment: If you install the `natsort` library, this is a single function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fint the first number sequence and cast it to int:

```
import re
def get_sorting(s):
    s = re.findall(r'^\d+[A-Z]\.', s)[0].rstrip('.')
    num = int(s[:-1])
    return num, s[-1]

arr = sorted(arr, key = get_sorting)
```

**update**

As suggested By @ Raj006 in comments if you want it to support many letters after number use below function instead :

```
def get_sorting(s):
    a = re.match('(\d+)([A-Z]*)\.', s) 
    number = int(a.group(1)) 
    text = a.group(2)
    return number,text
```

Comment: Change the regular expression to look from the beginning of the string `r'^\d+[A-Z]\.'` to be more explicit. Otherwise, the solution looks good.

Comment: x is not defined in line 3

Comment: giving an error list index out of range when replaced x with s

Comment: `a = re.match('(\d+)([A-Z]*)\.', s)`
`number = int(a.group(1))`
`text = a.group(2)`
`return number, text`
This will give you a complete solution, and of course `natsort` library will also do that.

Comment: Let me check it , are you sure you are testing the function for the given input?